# Template items not mapped to WFFM form

Tags: wffm

Using sc8.0u5 with WFFM u4

1. The WFFM that is assigned to a page doesn't load in the live mode. It shows in preview/exp. editor though.
2. Also, I'm mapping template fields to the WFFM form fields. After Save&close, when I open the form again in form designer, all the mappings are gone and it shows as "Not Defined".

Not just the field mappings, but also the "Template" & "Destination", that are set for this form, in the previous screen, are not saved.

These issues occur only in our QA environment and not local. Both use the same versions of sitecore and wffm.

Could this be a bug.

[image]

Comment: What version of WFFM are you using?

Comment: @DylanYoung I'm using WFFM4..the same one which is suggested for sc8.0u5

Comment: Before that screen when you specify a Template and Destination, what did you put for those options?  And assuming Template is a custom structure, could you provide details about what fields are a part of that template?  I just tested this but using a slightly newer version of Sitecore and WFFM and I'm seeing Not Defined, but when I click I see the fields.  So its possible it might be fixed in a newer version (which I will test your specific version tomorrow) or it might very well have something to do with the Template you've selected initially.

Comment: @DylanYoung all the fields in the template are single-line-text. This is working fine in local.Issue occurs only when moved to QA. Both environments use sc8.0 u5 and the same version of WFFM

Comment: @DylanYoung The template and destination values are also not saved. Though the text remains correct in the field, when clicked on browse, its always the "Home" item that is selected. Works good in local. Issue is in QA. I have updated this in OP.

Comment: And you're sure the form, the form definition, everything related to the form - is actually published, right?  When something works in preview but not in normal mode, publishing is near the number 1 culprit. See also: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/926033

Comment: @MarkCassidy Yes Mark..Thats the first thing I checked and it is published.